# String comparison in single brackets in zsh

Tags: bash, zsh, test

Bash code to print all folders:

```
for f in ~/*;
do
if [ $f  == '/home/sk/.' -o $f  == '/home/sk/..' ]; then
       true
  else
     echo "$f"
  fi
done
```

It works on bash. When i ran the code on z shell, it threw error:

```
 = not found
```

Then I converted `[` into `[[`, `]` into `]]` to avoid this error in z shell and ran it on z shell. It threw next error:

```
condition expected: $f
```

With `[[` and `]]`, bash also throws error as:

```
syntax error in conditional expression
syntax error near `-o'
```

Is there a POSIX standard to do string comparison in shell, that works across shells?

Comment: The POSIX standard for string comparison is [`case`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_04) which supports an arbitrary number of shell patterns applied against a string and arbitrary associated shell commands you might apply when a match is true.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There are various issues here. First, `==` is not standard. The POSIX way is `=`. Same goes for the `-o`. This one will work on both bash and zsh:

```
for f in ~/*;
do
if [ "$f"  = '/home/sk/.' ] || [ "$f"  = '/home/sk/..' ]; then
       true
  else
     echo "$f"
  fi
done
```

Note that your `if` is unneeded, dotfiles are ignored by default in both bash and zsh. You can simply write:

```
for f in ~/*; do echo "$f"; done
```

Or even

```
printf "%s\n" ~/*
```

Comment: hi terdon, i have set `shopt` for `dotglob` set as `off`. But still i am getting `.` and `..` inside the for loop in bash. so, i chose to do this fix... `ls -a` also lists the two entries - `.` and `..`

Comment: @MadhavanKumar if you are seeing dotfiles, then `dotglob` is set somehow. They won't appear otherwise.

Comment: @MadhavanKumar In bash, set `GLOBIGNORE=.:..` to skip `.` and `..`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
if [ "$f" = '/home/sk/.' ] || [ "$f" = '/home/sk/..' ]
```

Comment: Are there any shells that will include dotfiles when expanding `*`? Neither bash  nor zsh do.

Comment: @terdon; Not any shell that I know of. - Note that I was addressing just the OP's question in my answer, not any optimization beyond.

Comment: I understood that, hence my upvote. Since I'm pretty sure your knowledge of the shell ecosystem is far more extensive than my own, I thought I'd ask just in case :)

Comment: @terdon Neither does by default, but ksh, bash and zsh can be configured to include dot files.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but the conditions are unnecessary, since in the POSIX spec `*` will not expand to `.` or `..`

Also, you mentioned wanting to print all folders so then you would need to specify a trailing `/` in the pattern

So something like this should suffice to print all non-hidden directories..

```
for d in ~/*/
do
  [ -d "$f" ] && printf "%s\n" "${d%/}"
done
```

Note the the test for a directory entry, otherwise the pattern would get printed if there are no directories. `${d%/}` is used to remove the trailing `/` induced by the pattern.